# How to change a label's text after loading a html into a dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am opening a modal dialog by loading a form into it. After loading the form, I want to change it's title and one of it's fields' label. I can change the label's text, but after the function returns, the label's text turns back to it's original one. Is it possible to make this kind of change and if so, how?

The HTML:

```
<form action="testing.php" method="POST" id="example-form">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="link" id="link-label"></label>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

The javascript:

```
$(".bt-example").button().click(function() {
$('#example-dialog').load('form.html').dialog('open');
$('.ui-dialog-titlebar').text("THIS WORKS!");
$('#example-form #link-label').text("CHANGES AT FIRST, BUT GOES BLANK LATER");
$('#example-dialog').removeClass('invisible');
});
```

Comment: Make  a fiddle for your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you need to be more specific with your targetting... For example when changing `#link-label`:

```
$('#example-dialog').find('#link-label').text('Changes at first, and should stay...');
```

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. Just to be clearer, if I place a breakpoint after I change the label's text, it seems that it worked fine, but if I hit continue, then the text goes back to blank.